# How to get a method to run a certain amount of times

Tags: java, swing, methods, jpanel

I have made a game in java however it only runs one round. i want it to be able to run a certain amount of times based on a number pressed in a dialouge box. I think the answer is to run the method after one game is finished although i am unsure how to do this.

creation of jframe and metthod

```
public Rockgame() {

    // JFrame
    p = new ImagePanel(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("space.jpg"));
    f = new JFrame("SpaceMiners");

    f.setSize(700, 500);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The button which determines the amount of times run:

```
Object[] options = { "Three", "Five", "Ten" };
    no_of_games = (int) JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(f,
            "Would you like to play best of:", "Rounds" + "",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[2]);

if (no_of_games == 0) {
        no_of_games = no_of_games + 3;
    }
    if (no_of_games == 1) {
        no_of_games = no_of_games + 4;
    }
    if (no_of_games == 2) {
        no_of_games = no_of_games + 8;
    }
```

Creating the grid and the mouselistener

```
p.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

            playingGrid[x][y] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("rock.png"));
            p.add(playingGrid[x][y]);

            playingGrid[x][y].addMouseListener(new Rockbreaker());

        }
    }

}

public class Rockbreaker implements MouseListener {
    // manbitesdog6
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // sets all columns greater than one clicked to invisible

            if (e.getSource() == playingGrid[0][0]){
                for(int u =0;u<10;u++){
                for(int y =0;y<10;y++){
                Rockgame();

                }
            }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                    if (playingGrid[x][y] == e.getSource()) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                if ((i >= x) && (k >= y)) {
                                    playingGrid[i][k].setVisible(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is the code that = a round (of which you want 3, 5 or 10) in a function or is it all over the place? TL;DR can I call something like startRound()

Comment: The part where they click on the game is in a mouselistener i dont think it is

Comment: what is in the RockGame() function?

Comment: in the rockGame() method the grid is created and images are given to it as well as the jframe etc. then in the mouselistener that i added to the playing grid I have a loop that makes the one on the grid dissapear. when i click the one in the top left i want to reset the grid for another round. if that makes sense

Comment: Makes plenty when does the user enter the number of rounds?

Comment: Before the JFrame is made in a dialouge box

Comment: So put the game is a while loop that runs as long as current round (variable ticked up when game is reset/specific square is clicked) is less then num_of_games

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `for()`-loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < no_of_games; i++) {
     /*
      * Start game
      * Reset grid / panel
      * ...
      */
}
```

Also, have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: I've tried that but it just says the for loop is doing nothing.

Comment: Yes, because there is just a comment in the loop in my example code.

You of course should implement your code yourself, I just gave you the example code for a for()-loop which currently does nothing.

I won't implement that for you - it's your turn now ...